# Bootstrap - Rows inside div with justify content center not being place vertically after each row?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Below is my html code,

```
<div class="row mt-2 justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
        <figure>
            <img src="../img/dummy.jpg" class="rounded" />
            <figcaption class="text-center"><h3>Title</h3></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the output

[image: Output]

How do I make the buttons to be place below figure?

Comment: Try addding `flex-column` on the parent `div`

Comment: @T0ny1234 Adding flex-column made the buttons go down but the content longer justified center, all content went to the left.